# EL : Sintaxis Ilegal. en JSF + primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Por favor quisiera saber que está mal en esta expresión.

```
<p:inputText id="text_url"
            disabled="#{menuBean.tipoMenu.equalsIgnoreCase('I')?false:true}"
            value="#{menuBean.tipoMenu.equals('I')?menuBean.menu.formularioAsociado:'#'}"
            style="width: 400px" required="false"
            requiredMessage="Completar URL!" />
```

Me manda el siguiente error.

```
GRAVE: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /administrador/menu.xhtml @68,42 value="#{menuBean.tipoMenu.equalsIgnoreCase('I')?menuBean.menu.formularioAsociado:'#'}": Sitáxis ilegal para Operación de Poner Valor
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:868)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:751)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.Fieldset.processUpdates(Fieldset.java:232)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processUpdates(Layout.java:255)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /administrador/menu.xhtml @68,42 value="#{menuBean.tipoMenu.equalsIgnoreCase('I')?menuBean.menu.formularioAsociado:'#'}": Sitáxis ilegal para Operación de Poner Valor
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:834)
... 37 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Sitáxis ilegal para Operación de Poner Valor
at org.apache.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:137)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
... 38 more
```

Y el contexto es este. Ese input tiene dos 'escenarios' por así decirlo. En una escribes la URL del menu y en otra no. Para el segundo caso quise evita dejar el input en blanco y poner un valor. Y si ven en el atributo anterior la caja ya no se puede editar en ese mismo caso. El valor con el cual se evalúa la condición proviene de un combo que dejo a continuación. El combo cumple con lo que quiero satisfactoriamente.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="text_tip" value="#{menuBean.tipoMenu}"
                onchange="">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="SubMenu" itemValue="S" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item" itemValue="I" />
    <p:ajax update="text_url" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Gracias de antemano cualquier ayuda. :)

Comment: ¿Puedes poner al menos el tag completo?

Comment: Okis. Ahí está. Espero me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

En un `<p:inputText/>` (y otros tipos de input) la expresión no solo se usa para "leer" el valor al preparar el HTML, sino que también se usa para indicar dónde se debe escribir, al procesar el formulario, el valor devuelto por el usuario.

Naturalmente, para escribir ese valor en una propiedad la expresión debe indicar una propiedad. La formula que tú indicas no puede ser evaluada así, por lo que te da el valor.

Normalmente harás

```
<p:inputText value="#{menuBean.valorDelInputText}"/>
```

Ahora, para que la propiedad sea legible necesitas que exista el `getter`; para que se pueda modificar (`writtable`) ha de exister el `setter` de la propiedad:

```
public class MenuBean {

    public String getValorDelInputText() {
       ...
    }

    public void setValorDelInputText(String valor) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Si quieres inicializar el valor, el mejor lugar para hacerlo es en el `@PostConstruct` o en algún controlador de eventos de JSF que corresponda.

Como curiosidad, este uso del EL es lo que hace que se use `#{}` en vez de `${}`; con `${}` se evalúa la expresión una vez y se substituye, con `#{}` se calcula la expresión pero se sigue manteniendo la expresión para volverla a evaluar más adelante si es necesario.

UPDATE: Por favor, no cambies la pregunta una vez contestada; si tu objetivo cambia siempre puedes crear una nueva pregunta.

En todo caso, si tienes que ejecutar lógica al hacer una invocación con `p:ajax` usando el atributo `listener`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Me quedo con el último párrafo que no la sabía ni nunca me la había preguntado. Mi problema iba más por lo que mencionas en el penúltimo párrafo, pero quería evitarme la chamba en el bean usando esa EL. Voy a actualizar la pregunta para que se entienda el contexto.

Answer (score 0):

En la vista, en la parte donde usted está indicando el valor, debe asignarle un valor válido o remover esa propiedad (la propiedad value).

Asegúrese de que está apuntando a una variable que existe, de lo contrario, como dije anteriormente, proceda a eliminar la propiedad "value"

Ejemplo correcto:

```
value="#{miBean.nombre}"
```

Ejemplos incorrectos:

```
value=""
value="#{}"
```